# How to make a PHP variable accessible from every webpage?

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to create a variable, set its value through a webpage and make it accessible from code in other webpages?

If yes, how is this done in PHP?

Will the variable have a life time in memory if it is not used for a long time?

Comment: do you have any idea about SESSION and COOKIES?

Comment: yes I go with @MixedVeg, Use SESSION

Comment: No, i'm not used to server based environments. The idea is creating a buffer with information that is supposed to remain in memory constantly. Will the SESSION have a life time?

Comment: Read manual about sessions

Comment: Declare in config or any globally accessble file and then use it with `global`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use session or cookie varibles (or)
2. declare in common file (or)
3. Try global variables (or)